# How can I merge 2 input values from a form before performing a form action?

Tags: php, html, forms, bing-maps

I am trying to create a form that gets a user directions to a pre-defined location from the location that they entered. I am using Bing Maps 'create a custom url map' to achieve this.

Based on msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx) I know I need the form to pass a single value such as the following: rtp=adr.'addressfromuser'~adr.'predefined address' . I just don't know how to merge the form values (or insert adr. in front of the user input). I have been unable to find a way to do this so any help is appreciated.

my code for my form is below:

```
<form action="http://bing.com/maps/default.aspx" method="get" target="_blank">
    <label for="rtp">From:</label>
    <input class ="input" type="text" name="rtp" value="adr." /> <!--user input-->
    <input type="hidden" name="rtp" value="~adr.Mission,TX" />
    <!--predetermined destination-->
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" type="submit" value="Get directions" />
</form>
```

Ding this gets a result that is close to what I want but not quite there (would like to hide the initial "adr." and not generate a "rtp=" before the 2nd rtp being passed. **Note: if I comment out the user inputs I successfully get a map with the final destination as point b, but no point a defined**

If what I'm trying to do is possible help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to array your ftp input:

EDIT: YOU NEED TO REMOVE `adr.` in the `value="adr."` on both `rtp` inputs!

```
<form action="http://bing.com/maps/default.aspx" method="get" target="_blank">
    <label for="rtp">From:</label>
    <input class ="input" type="text" name="rtp[]" value="" /> <!--user input-->
    <input type="hidden" name="rtp[]" value="Mission,TX" />
    <!--predetermined destination-->
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Get directions" />
</form>
```

Then, when you process the form, you would `implode()` that `rtp[]` array like so:

```
<?php
/* $_GET['rtp']  will look like this before implosion:
array(
    0 => FromCity,UT
    1 => ToCity,CA
    ) 
*/

// You need to pre-append the adr. value to both strings by looping array
foreach($_GET['rtp'] as $value) {
        $_rtp[] =   "adr.'".$value."'";
    }
/* Now $_rtp looks like this:
array(
        0 => adr.'FromCity,UT'
        1 => adr.'ToCity,UT'
    )
*/

// Now implode this new array with "~"
// You could assign a new variable to the implode, but if you wanted to,
// you could override the same $_GET['rtp'] variable with it's imploded self.

$_GET['rtp']        =   implode("~",$_rtp);

// Now the $_GET['ftp'] = adr.'FromCity,UT'~adr.'ToCity,UT'
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. I tried using an array earlier. The problem that occurs for me is that for each element is is proceeded by rtp = (I would only want rtp there once). I've done some reading on the implode function, and it looks promising by using an empty glue, though I'm still not sure how to make the array implode before the form.

Comment: I will modify my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

use javascript/jquery

```
$('form').submit(function(){
//do your actions here


$('input[name=rtp]').value()

return false; // prevents submit by default action.
});
```

Comment: thanks this looks promising. I will have to read up on jquery, it laso looks like I may need to use AJAX with this approach?

Comment: only if you need to update your page display value depending on the return value of user input after server processing. If there is no such step then you can just either NOT have the hidden input and then use `.append ('<input text/>');` to add the field on 2nd input, or do value combines with `$first.value($first.value + $second.value)` (not the exact syntax)